granting privileges to user in postgresql
I'm trying to setup a new project with a Postgresql 15.5 database.
I have a running instance. If I create a new database
psql --command "create database \"tagger-db\""

create a new user
psql --command "create user \"tagger-user\""

grant all privileges on the new database to the new user
psql --command "grant all privileges on database \"tagger-db\" to \"tagger-user\""

if I then try to create a table with the new user
psql -U "tagger-user" -d "tagger-db" --command "create table users (id uuid primary key)"

I get the following error
ERROR:  permission denied for schema public

what is the correct way to grant to the new user all the privileges on the the database?

try GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO EXAMPLE_USER; as the database owner. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67276391/why-am-i-getting-a-permission-denied-error-for-schema-public-on-pgadmin-4/67276542#67276542
